# pytorch: get number of classes given an ImageFolder dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

If I have a dataset like:

```
image_datasets['train'] = datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, transform=train_transforms)
```

How do I determine programatically the number of classes or unique labels in the dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
len(image_datasets['train'].classes)
```

`.classes` returns a list.

Comment: Wait, so you asked a question and abruptly answered it yourself?

Comment: @DirtyBit Yes, this is encouraged on meta. There is a "Answer your own question" button after typing the question, so both are posted at once.

Answer (score 6):

In case your data type is a tensor then you can use:

```
import torch  
n_classes = len(torch.unique(Your_Target_Vector))
```